# Axios not working for accessing getpocket api

Tags: javascript, api, axios, pocket

I can make the oauth request using curl but using axios I get a error about missing consumer key

X-Error 
Missing consumer key.

This happens in the OPTIONS phase of making the request.

```js
 axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://getpocket.com/v3/oauth/request',
  data: {
    'consumer_key': 'xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8080/'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the curl request

```
curl https://getpocket.com/v3/oauth/request --insecure -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Accept: application/json" -d "{\"consumer_key\":\"xxxx-xxxxxx\",\"redirect_uri\":\"http://localhost:8080/\"}"
```

Comment: I bet this is CORS-related. Is it the `POST` itself that is getting that error, or is there a pre-flight `OPTIONS` request that is getting the error? Also, maybe the error message is bad and the API _requires_ that `X-Accept: application/json` header, which your axios example isn't using.

Comment: Running that snippet above confirms: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: It's the pre-flight OPTIONS that is getting the error. If it's a CORS error why does curl work?

Comment: CORS is just a browser thing, so executing this from a server or from a command line won't require CORS.

Comment: Looks like you aren't the first running across this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35194986/setting-headers-and-sending-data-with-http-post-to-pocket-api-returns-cors

Comment: Thanks @Jacob I guess I can't do what I wanted without a server.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the headers to your request for it to accept json:

```
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    },
    url: 'https://getpocket.com/v3/oauth/request',
    data: {
        'consumer_key': 'xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8080/'
    }
});
```